# numbers with asterisk

Tags: java, loops

Im new to java and i wonder that if it is possible to put asterisk beside the numbers,
example:
1*
2**
3***

I have here my code

```
package ReviewExercise;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class review1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number from 1 - 10: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        //for(int r = 1; ; r++){
            for(int c = 1; c <= num; c++) {
                for (int r = c; r <= c; r++) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Briefly

```
for (int i = 0 i < noOfAsterisks; i++) {
   System.out.print("*");
}
```

Note the usage of `print()` rather than `println()`. `print()` won't print a line-feed after its output, and as such can be used to print out sequences such as the above.

You may prefer to use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build a string in memory, and then print it out in one `println()` statement. That may be more efficient and/or nicer.

Comment: the output should look like this:

`1*`

`2**`

`3***`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `for` loop as following:

```
for(int c = 1; c <= num; c++) 
{
    System.out.print(c);
    for (int r = 1; r <= c; r++) 
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int c = 1; c <= num; c++)
{
    String line = String.valueOf(c);
    for (int r = 0; r < c; r++)
    {
        line += "*";
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(line);
 }
```

Comment: change to this System.out.print(r + "*");